# Enter Turkey from Budapest

Tags: visas, schengen, turkey

I am Egyptian, age above 45. I have a Schengen visa. Can I enter Turkey after getting an eVisa, but coming to Istanbul from Budapest with Turkish Airlines and leaving Istanbul back to Cairo through Aegean Airlines?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer of your question: **Yes** , you can enter Turkey with e-visa does not matter from where do you go to Turkey.

However, I guess you wanted to ask something else. Then I would suggest to:
-Explain the situation better! 
-Did you buy the tickets separately?
-Do you have a checked-in luggage?
-Does Aegean Airlines directly fly to Cairo from Istanbul?
-Do you have a multiple entry schengen visa, if you need to enter Greece?